# Generate Ant build option missing in Build menu

Tags: intellij-idea, ant

My intellij dosent have the generate ant build tool option that the oficial doc says
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-ant-build-file.html[enter link description here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-ant-build-file.html)

[image]

how can i make the option appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was [deprecated](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230080) and moved into a separate plug-in for those who still need it. So you need to install the [Ant Build Generation plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14169-ant-build-generation) to make it available.

We'll update the docs to mention it, thanks for the feedback.

Reason for the deprecation:

> The functionality is not maintained, doesn't support all types of
>   projects supported by the IDE and requires manual work to keep the
>   project in a state buildable on CI. It will be removed from the
>   product into a separate plugin, not bundled by default.
>
> The recommended replacement is to use Maven or Gradle for building the
>   project.

Comment: You help come just in time, i almost downgrade the version of intellij!.Thanks.

Comment: By the way, why is deprecated?

Comment: Linked the issue in YouTrack and quoted the reason in the answer.

Comment: We having a though moment trying to build the app... Anyway thank you very much!